# Set::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to Mathematica, I want to create a list(swarmCost) with values from the cost function, but I get this error,

```
Set::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist 
Set::partw: Part 2 of {} does not exist.
```

and so on. Could anyone please suggest where I am doing wrong?
The code snippet is as follows:

```
    swarmCost={};
swarmPosition={{4.50614,0.655981},{3.61431,0.0197775},{1.35872,-0.906011},{0.424309,-3.33389},{2.21984,4.61048},{-3.31068,2.74918},{4.03984,-3.09416},{4.73452,-0.647246},{-4.14072,-4.53264},{1.77801,1.37185}}
    FitnessFunction[x_]:=Module[{l = Length@x}, 
      2*l*(Sum[x[[i]]^2 - 10 * Cos[2 * Pi * x[[i]] ], {i, l}])];
    f[x__] := Re[Map[FitnessFunction, {x}]];
    Print["Function cost value", First@f[swarmPosition[[1]]]];// this print works ok for a single entry of swarmPosition
    
    For[i = 1, i <=  (NP), i++,
      swarmCost[[i]] = First@f[swarmPosition[[i]]];
      ];
    

//swarmCost is empty if printed after the loop and moreover, I get this error.
```

Comment: Use `Map` or `Table` instead of `For`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to allocate space first for `swarmCost`. Something like this (also you did not say what `NP` is. So I set it to 10 in this example

```
swarmPosition = {{4.50614, 0.655981}, {3.61431, 
   0.0197775}, {1.35872, -0.906011}, {0.424309, -3.33389}, {2.21984, 
   4.61048}, {-3.31068, 
   2.74918}, {4.03984, -3.09416}, {4.73452, -0.647246}, {-4.14072, 
-4.53264}, {1.77801, 1.37185}}

FitnessFunction[x_] := Module[{l = Length@x}, 
   2*l*(Sum[x[[i]]^2 - 10*Cos[2*Pi*x[[i]]], {i, l}])];

f[x__] := Re[Map[FitnessFunction, {x}]];

NP = 10; (*made up some value as was not given *)
swarmCost = Table[0, NP]; (*need to pre-allocate*)

For[i = 1, i <= (NP), i++, swarmCost[[i]] = First@f[swarmPosition[[i]]]]
```

And now

```
swarmCost
```

gives

```
{145.192, 42.6818, 2.69079, 100.862, 127.946, 89.1642, 31.6218, 
119.291, 164.566, 40.8887}
```

You can also do the above without the use of a `For` loop as this is not recommended in Mathematica. For example, you could replace your `For` loop with something like

```
swarmCost = First@f[swarmPosition[[#]]] & /@ Range[NP]
```

And if you had done the above, then you would not  had to pre-allocate. So you new code now becomes only this

```
swarmPosition={{4.50614,0.655981},{3.61431,0.0197775},{1.35872,-0.906011},{0.424309,-3.33389},{2.21984,4.61048},{-3.31068,2.74918},{4.03984,-3.09416},{4.73452,-0.647246},{-4.14072,-4.53264},{1.77801,1.37185}}

FitnessFunction[x_]:=Module[{l=Length@x},2*l*(Sum[x[[i]]^2-10*Cos[2*Pi*x[[i]]],{i,l}])];

f[x__]:=Re[Map[FitnessFunction,{x}]];
NP=10;
swarmCost=First@f[swarmPosition[[#]]]&/@Range[NP]
```